# Caching( optimizing) Strategy with API live stream on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, caching

So I built a website that uses Twitch.tv API, which is a gaming live stream website.  The requests are long and slow, and I would like to cache it somehow.  The problem is that there are a lot of dynamic attributes,  if they are still online, or how many viewers there are.  Since the traffic to my website is low at the moment, expiring Cache early isn't going to help much.  Also, I have a page where it lists all the live streams, and it requests to see if the stream is online.  So even if no one is online it still takes a while to load.  Is there anyway to retrieve api faster without caching?

here is [twitch.tv api doc](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't own the Twitch.tv API, unfortunately I would say there is really nothing you can do to make their calls faster.

The good news is that you can cache the calls you make to them, which will make things appear faster to your users.

The way to cache the calls is to create a key and then cache the return JSON from the API. To create the key I would just use the URL you are calling for the API. Then just give the cached value an expiration time of a few minutes and when it expires you make another API call to re-populate the cache.

Also I'd look at Varnish (https://www.varnish-cache.org/) which does a lot of HTTP caching really well. Could work really well for you and it has the concept of a grace period that tries to hide the expensive calls made when the cache expires.